# Difference in bitwise and logical and in python

Tags: python

I recently saw a question on the stack asking why the wrong if statement was being executed. Although I knew what to do to fix the code, i dont understand why the bitwise and is returning a true value.

```
win = 5
loss = 5

val = win>0 & loss == 0
print(val)
# True

val = (win>0) & (loss == 0)
print(val)
# False

val = win>0 and loss == 0
print(val)
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), following the example you can see that is equivalent saying:

```
val = win > (0 & loss) == 0
```

as we evaluate the expression, `(0 & loss)` becomes 0 that is smaller than win and equal to zero.